# composer rewrites my .env file by new generated one

Tags: symfony, symfony4

When I run composer install for my symfony project, my .env file is rewrote by new generated one. What should I do to save my .env intact?

Comment: .env should be kept in the repository now as it acts like a dist file now. You should use .env.local instead.

Comment: I keep my .env in repo. But composer install changes my file

Comment: There were [some changes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/dot-env-changes.html) in env handling

Comment: This is a desired behavior to keep all defaults there - https://symfony.com/blog/improvements-to-the-handling-of-env-files-for-all-symfony-versions

Answer (score 1):

Applications created after November 2018 had a slightly different system, read [changes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/dot-env-changes.html)

From the official [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#managing-multiple-env-files)

- `.env.local` : defines/overrides env vars for all environments but only in your local machine
- `.env` : defines the default value of env vars.

The `.env` and `.env.<environment>` files should be committed to the shared repository because they are the same for all developers. However, the `.env.local` and `.env.<environment>.local` and files **should not be committed** because only you will use them. In fact, the .gitignore file that comes with Symfony prevents them from being committed.

Comment: Yes, I did it. I put my .env in repo. But when I build docker image for my application, I run composer install what rewrites my .env.  But I want to keep my .env intact. Sure I made some workaround, but it's odd

Comment: When building your Docker image, you should copy a `.env.prod` never touch the original `.env`

Comment: Have you seen that original .env? it's just a stub. What's a reason to save it? And it's against https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/dot-env-changes.html